# Google app engine python images API reduce image size

Tags: python, google-app-engine, image-processing

I am currently handling images in my GAE application through the [Images Python API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages). I need to reduce the size of the JPG image files without cropping them. Is there any way to accomplish this? Sorry if this question has a very obvious answer, as I can not seem to be able to find any solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [example code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/images/guestbook/main.py#L122), it looks like you can just call `images.resize(image, width, height)`.

Also see the [Transforming Images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages#Transform) section in the documentation.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying. From what I could gather from the resize function, it is meant to change the dimensions of the image. But I want to reduce the size of the image file, without actually changing its dimensions. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh ... I think you probably need to be more specific about what you mean by size then.  I assumed you meant you wanted an output image with smaller dimensions :-).  You could try resizing the image down and then back up to the original size.  That may or may not work to reduce to total memory that the image takes -- particularly for lossy image formats like `.jpg`.  Out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this?  Storage space for images is pretty cheap so the filesize shouldn't impact the cost _too_ much.

Comment: I am sorry, I am a newbie when it comes to image processing, I will try to frame my question better and update it.
I need my server's clients to download these images on a regular basis, and the images are quite large for that purpose for now. An average image is ~100 kB, and even a 20-30% saving in the size will add up to a lot of savings on the client's side (it wouldn't matter even if the image quality would go down along with the size, I will try to hit the balance between the two aspects). Thanks :)

Comment: @TanmayGarg for regular/often access to the same image sizes you could try to take advantage of caching. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550066/how-to-use-cache-control-with-python-in-gae for example.